# How to locate app crash logs in Android phone?

Tags: android, crash

If any Android app crashes some crash logs are generated on behalf of that app. How to find the location of such crash logs.

I want crash logs inside the Android device, not really using Logcat to see the crash logs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Are u looking for the log generated while debugging or after distribution (on user's device)?

Answer (score 1):

In logcat stack trace, you can find exception/error details. Say for an example,

```
    04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onCreate(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:68)
    04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

here java.lang.NullPointerException thrown exception if you click com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onCreate(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:68) You can get where which throws null pointer exception in program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ACRA to see the stack trace when an app crashes on a device. It's a library and you can call its API wherever you want in your program. There are several choices for where to send the information, among them an email address. Here are the instructions for setting it up:
https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup